# Proper way to call a method in Model - Laravel

Tags: php, oop, laravel, methods, model

I have been trying to Call a Method in Model from a Controller Class in Laravel 5...

I tried using `static` keyword for the method in the Model and got it working... But i couldnt make it static in future...

Controller File

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Offer;

class TestController extends Controller {
    public function testFunction()
    {
        $lat = "12.971891";
        $lon = "77.5945627";
        $radius = "10";  

       $result = Offer::featuredOffers($lat, $lon, $radius);

       return response()->json($result);

    }
}
```

Model File

```
    //Model to Return Featured Offers
        public static function featuredOffers($lat="", $lon ="", $radius="")
        {
            //Return All Featured Offers if any of the Params Missing
            if(($lat == "") || ($lon == "") || ($radius == "")){
                return Offer::select("_id","bannerimage","offername", "offer")->where("featured","=", 1)->where("bannerimage", "!=", "")->where('expirydate', '>', new DateTime('-1 day'))->where('startdate', '<', new DateTime())->where("status", "=", 1)->get();
            }

            else{
            //Would Add more complex code here later
            return "Lon :".$lon." | Lat :".$lat." | Radius :".$radius."";

            }
}
```

As of now it works.. But as soon as I remove the `static` keyword from the Method.. It doesnt... I read somewhere i have to instantiate an Object for calling the Model method from Controller... I'm now grasping OOP concepts and Laravel.. How should I do it the proper way.

Could somebody help out

Answer (score 0):

You just instantiate an instance of your model:

```
public function testFunction()
{
    $lat = "12.971891";
    $lon = "77.5945627";
    $radius = "10";  

    $offer = new Offer();
    $result = $offer->featuredOffers($lat, $lon, $radius);

    return response()->json($result);

}
```